# AdBanner View not fitting correctly on iPhone 5

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I have created an AdBannerView in my xCode Project and set the size programatically like this:

```
    [bannerView_ setFrame:CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-bannerView_.frame.size.width,
                                [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-bannerView_.frame.size.height - [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height,
                                bannerView_.frame.size.width,
                                bannerView_.frame.size.height
                                )];
```

The issue I have is that on iOS7/iPhone5 the ad doesnt touch the bottom of the screen. I also need to ensure it fits correctly on iPhone 4 and iOS6.

I'd appreciate some help with this, thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this part of your code:

```
 - [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height
```

Your ad is offset by exactly that amount.